# What does W.I.S.E. stand for in Psyren?

Tags: psyren

I may have missed this in the manga somewhere, but what does W.I.S.E. stand for in Psyren?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The organization's name W.I.S.E is not an acronym. It is simply called WISE (ワイズ) in original Japanese.

[image: W.I.S.E poster]

Note the missing dot at the end, suggesting that the dots between the letters are only used for decoration.

---

<sub>Note: I have researched on English sites ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyren) & [Wikia](http://psyren.wikia.com/wiki/WISE)), and also Japanese sites ([Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSYREN_-%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3-), [atwiki](http://www23.atwiki.jp/psy_ren/pages/73.html), [NicoNicoPedia](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/psyren)), and no sites mention the full form of W.I.S.E</sub>